# Serial exception Arduino to Python error

Tags: python, arduino

I want to read data from Arduino and store in a text file in pc through serial port using pyserial whenever I try to execute the Python code it gives this message I tried many things but didn't work out.

[image]

Code:

```
import io
    import serial
    from datetime import datetime
    from serial import SerialException
    connected=False
    outfile='C:\Users\Yassine\hello.txt'
    ser = serial.Serial(port="COM12", baudrate=9600,timeout=None,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser, 1), encoding='ascii', newline ='\r')
    with open(outfile,'a') as f:
     while ser.isOpen():
        try:
          datastring=ser.readline()
        except serial.SerialException:
         pass
        print datastring
        print datetime.now()
        f.write(datetime.now().isoformat() +'\t'+ datastring +'\n' )
        f.flush() 

        while not ser.isOpen():
           pass
           ser.close()
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post!

Comment: Pro-tip: console output is a text artefact, so please post it as text. Would you delete that image and replace it with the equivalent text, in a formatted block? Remember that images are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines, and thus they make it harder for readers to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check that COM12 is actually the Arduino by looking in device manager.
Or you can execute this in command line to get a list of available serial ports:

```
python -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

You may also have something else trying to access the Arduino serial port. Make sure the Serial Monitor in Arduino IDE is closed.

Comment: @YassineYassine What's not working? Did you see the arduino in the list?

Comment: it's ok I tried another code & it's  working thanks Im working now on other stuff reading from txt & assign some values  to another txt if you could help with it using python

Answer (score 0):

I want to open txt file read the last value of it & write it in other txt file,it's working but the reading value(arg) written to the next file jump the line which is not good for me i want it at the same line with other variables
`with open(outfile,'a') as f:
      with open (inputfile,'r') as f1:
           arg =f1.readline()    // that variable i read from the txt
           print (arg )
           f.write(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d ; %H:%M:%S")+'\n'+valueRead+ '\n' +arg+ '\n')     // the file i write to 
           f.flush()
           f1.close()
           f.close()`

TTTs (this is my arg variable that i read from txt file this is what i get)

2017-05-12 ; 15:48:23   TTS (this is how i want it )

Thanks for helping guys